# Is it possible to link a Range and a Numerical HTML input?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, input

Is there a way to link the values of a `<input type="range">` and an `<input type="number">`?

I would like to make changes to either the slider ***or*** to the numerical input and have both fields be updated. For some reason I have only been able to get an undefined value from the *range* element as of yet.

Here is my current JavaScript and HTML for this part of the document:

```js
function updateTextInput1(val) {
  alert(val);
  document.getElementById('num1').value = val;
}
```

```html
<input class="inputRange" type="range" min="0" max="100" onchange="updateTextInput1(this.val)" />
<input class="inputNumber" id="num1" min="0" max="100" type="number" value="0" />
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's not working because `updateTextInput1(this.val)` should be `updateTextInput1(this.value)`:

```js
function updateTextInput1(val) {
  document.getElementById('num1').value = val;
}
```

```html
<input class="inputRange" type="range" min="0" max="100" onchange="updateTextInput1(this.value)" />
<input class="inputNumber" id="num1" min="0" max="100" type="number" value="0" />
```

However, I'd suggest using [unobtrusive JavaScript](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unobtrusive_JavaScript), though.

Just attach an `input` event to each element. In doing so, both elements will be in sync.

```js
var range = document.querySelector('.inputRange');
var field = document.getElementById('num1');

range.addEventListener('input', function (e) {
  field.value = e.target.value;
});
field.addEventListener('input', function (e) {
  range.value = e.target.value;
});
```

```html
<input class="inputRange" type="range" min="0" max="100" value="0" />
<input class="inputNumber" id="num1" min="0" max="100" type="number" value="0" />
```

Or you could use a more compact approach and select the sibling element:

```js
document.querySelector('.inputRange').addEventListener('input', updateValue);
document.getElementById('num1').addEventListener('input', updateValue);

function updateValue (e) {
  var sibling = e.target.previousElementSibling || e.target.nextElementSibling;
  sibling.value = e.target.value;
}
```

```html
<input class="inputRange" type="range" min="0" max="100" value="0"/>
<input class="inputNumber" id="num1" min="0" max="100" type="number" value="0" />
```

Comment: I'd use `input` event to update numeric input while changing too

Answer (score 2):

The error is: *this.val* instead of **this.value**

```js
function updateTextInput1(val) {
  alert(val);
  document.getElementById('num1').value = val;
}
```

```html
<input class="inputRange" type="range" min="0" max="100" onchange="updateTextInput1(this.value)" />
<input class="inputNumber" id="num1" min="0" max="100" type="number" value="0" />
```

Answer (score 2):

To display everytime the range or input text is changing you can use `oninput` and `onchange` on the input range, and also `onkeypress` and `onchange` on the input type text :

```js
function updateTextInput1(val) {
  val = val > 100 ? 100 : val;
  val = val < 0 ? 0 : val;
  document.getElementById('range').value = val;
  document.getElementById('num1').value = val;
}
```

```html
    <input class="inputRange" id="range" type="range" min="0" max="100" oninput="updateTextInput1(this.value)" onchange="updateTextInput1(this.value)" />
    <input class="inputNumber" id="num1" min="0" max="100" type="number" value="0" onkeypress="updateTextInput1(this.value)" onchange="updateTextInput1(this.value)" />
```

Answer (score 1):

You should bind event using js/jq. And to link both, you could target specific sibling element (or any other relevant transversal method):

```js
$('.inputRange, .inputNumber').on('input', function(){
  $(this).siblings('.inputRange, .inputNumber').val(this.value);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input class="inputRange" type="range" min="0" max="100" value="0"/>
<input class="inputNumber" id="num1" min="0" max="100" type="number" value="0" />
```

Comment: It's a nice reply, but why use jquery everywhere ? ^^ You can also create a NodeJs server, add MeteorJS. Create some method on server side to update a MongoDB when the input type range is updated, and publish this change to the client to update the input text ^^

Comment: @Arthur Well, i'm not using jQuery everywhere, just when coding... :) Here that's just because OP tagged question with `jQuery`. So if OP is already using jQuery, for consitency in code, he should use jQuery... Now you'd have better to ask OP why he used jQuery tag, don't you?!